# How to initialize array out of the class and set a value to the first element?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static, initialization

Use in Arduino. The problem is there: Player::coords[0] = {0, 0};

Heading file:

```cpp
#ifndef game_h
#define game_h
#include <Arduino.h>

class Player {
  public:
    int getScore();
    static int coords[3250][2];
    coordinates: x, y

  private:
    static int score;
};

#endif
```

Cpp file:

```cpp
#include "game.h"

int Player::score = 1;

int Player::getScore() {
  return this->score;
}

int Player::coords[3250][2];
Player::coords[0] = {0, 0};
```

Compiler writes: 'coords' in 'class Player' does not name a type

Comment: You can't assign variables outside of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not do this way at a namespace scope

```
int Player::coords[3250][2];
Player::coords[0] = {0, 0};
```

In fact these statements are equivalent to this one

```
int Player::coords[3250][2] = { { 0, 0 } };
```

or

```
int Player::coords[3250][2] = {};
```

or even just

```
int Player::coords[3250][2];
```

because the array has the static storage duration and zero-initialized by the compiler.